# Android ListView item onClick

Tags: android, android-listview

I am developing an Android app with a lot of ListView's. i created my own ListAdapter but i am not so happy with the OnItemClickListener. What is the best way to add a listener on an item if every item has other functionality?

Comment: you can set the clickListener in `getView` method of adapter

Comment: What do you mean by `add a listener on an item if every item has other functionality`?

Comment: it is better you post your getView code.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, I'm using this Custom Adapter & OnClickListener()

```
   public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Activity activity;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private List<Jobs> jobsItems;

        public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Jobs> jobsItems) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.jobsItems = jobsItems;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return jobsItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int location) {
            return jobsItems.get(location);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (inflater == null)
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_row_no_preview, null);

          Button submit = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
          serial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                }
            });


            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

Similarly you can add any TextView, EditText or Button into your ListView and set onCickListener()